# What is maximum payload size in python-socketio and how to extend it?

Tags: python, python-socketio

I'm trying to send the `bytes` data of the raw FullHD 32-bit color depth frame (which is about 3.6MB) on the payload, while emitting event, to the server.

Here's the code handling that.
The `data_chunk` is a `UstreamChunk` object with its definition copied below.

```py
self.sio.emit("process", data_chunk.to_json())

class UstreamChunk:
    def __init__(self, chunk: bytes, part_number: int):
        self.data = chunk
        self.part_number = part_number

    def to_json(self) -> Dict:
        return {
            "data_chunk": self.data,
            "part_number": self.part_number,
        }
```

The best I could actually do, however, is to send 360p frame..
Its' size is about 0.88MB.

Everything that's longer, like 16-bit HD frame (1.76MB) is lost on the way to the server.

The event/message doesn't even hit the server.
Is it possible, that this behavior is related to maximum payload size?

Comment: Did you try increasing the `max_http_buffer_size` option of the server? The default is 1MB.

Comment: No. How can I do that? @MiguelGrinberg

Comment: This is an option that you pass to the server when you create it. See the [docs](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#server-class) if you need more details.